# Merge 2 files line by line in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, text-editing

I have 2 files and I want to merge them line bye line.

For example the content of 1st file is:

```
python create-account.py un1 example.com 123456
python create-account.py un2 example.com 123456
python create-account.py un3 example.com 123456
python create-account.py un4 example.com 123456
python create-account.py un5 example.com 123456
```

And the content of 2nd file is:

```
"fn1" 123456
"fn2" 123456
"fn3" 123456
"fn4" 123456
"fn5" 123456
```

output result must be like below lines:

```
python create-account.py un1 example.com 123456 "fn1" 123456
python create-account.py un2 example.com 123456 "fn2" 123456
python create-account.py un3 example.com 123456 "fn3" 123456
python create-account.py un4 example.com 123456 "fn4" 123456
python create-account.py un5 example.com 123456 "fn5" 123456
```

this script designed to add users to a database

Which command do I need to use?

Comment: I think you need to also clarify and give an example of the expected output results based on your examples that you are expecting. Please do a simple [edit] and add this detail.

Comment: Try this `paste -d @ a.txt b.txt | sed -e 's/@/\n/g' | sed '/^$/d'`

Comment: merely `paste file1 file2`  no ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `paste` command:

> paste 1st 2nd